# php artisan migrate throws PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I found other thread with the same issue however I didn't fix it. The doc says I should just uncomment the extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll line which I did. I'm running Windows with xampp and I'm trying to connect to the MySql db.
However I get this error:

```
$ php artisan migrate
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for  user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\your-project-name\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
```

I modified the database.php file with the right MySql credentials so I don't how why I get an error saying I'm trying to connect with the homestead username since I don't use it.
I eventually tried to use homestead but I also get an error related to the PDO extension when I try to install it

Comment: Are you properly [detecting your environment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration)?

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. I had to modify the credentials in my .env file. Could you explain what's the database.php there from then?

Comment: In `.env` file you specify your credential for this specific environment. This file has different content on your development machine and on your production server. In `config/database.php` you specify app-specific values, which are the same on local/development and production. This file reads database credentials from `.env` and if not specified there, it uses default values from second parameter of `env()` helper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change .env File in Laravel Root Directory.
Give proper credential and also make sure that given database name is exists in MYSQL.

Then after modifying .env File , make changes to config/database.php here use env so that it will check for that variable in .env File.If not found then it will use 2nd parameter as value.

```
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel5'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'ganesh'),
```